# Dificuldade ao resolver um problema Jmedia de Idade em JAVA

Tags: java

Ola estou com dificuldade ao resolver um desafio sendo este:
Faça um algoritmo para ler um número indeterminado de dados, contendo cada um, a idade de um indivíduo. O último dado, que não entrará nos cálculos, contém o valor de idade negativa. Calcular e imprimir a idade média deste grupo de indivíduos.

Entrada
A entrada contém um número indeterminado de inteiros. A entrada será encerrada quando um valor negativo for lido.

Saída
A saída contém um valor correspondente à média de idade dos indivíduos.

A média deve ser impressa com dois dígitos após o ponto decimal.

```
``**import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  Desafio {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cont = 0;
        int soma = 0;
        int n = leitor.nextInt();
        
        while (n >= 1){
            if (n >= 0) {
                soma+= n ;
                cont++;
            }
            n = leitor.nextInt();
        }
        double media =    soma / cont      ;
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",  media   ));
    }
}**``
```

Answer (score 0):

``**import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  Desafio {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
int cont = 0;
double soma = 0;
int n = leitor.nextInt();

```
    while (n >= 1){
        if (n >= 0) {
            soma+= n ;
            cont++;
        }
        n = leitor.nextInt();
    }
    double media =    soma / cont      ;
    System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",  media   ));
}
```

}**``

Mudei a variavel soma de INT pra DOUBLE e deu certo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).